# How would I create a list based on matching path strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm basically trying to seperate file path strings into lists of files in the same path. Lets say I have this list:

```
files = ['user/hey.jpg','user/folder1/1.txt','user/folder1/folder2/random.txt',
         'user/folder1/blah.txt','user/folder3/folder4/folder5/1.txt',
         'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/3.txt','user/folder3/folder4/folder5/2.txt',
         'user/1.jpg']
```

I'm looking to get this output (not concerned about the order):

```
[
 ['user/folder1/1.txt','user/folder1/blah.txt']
 ['user/folder1/folder2/random.txt']
 ['user/folder3/folder4/folder5/1.txt',
  'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/2.txt','user/folder3/folder4/folder5/3.txt']
 ['user/1.jpg','user/hey.jpg']
]
```

Sorry if my example is sloppy. Typing on a phone is no fun. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `os.path.dirname` as key in `sorted` and `groupby` functions should lead you to the results:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby
[list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(files, key=os.path.dirname), key=os.path.dirname)]

#[['user/hey.jpg', 'user/1.jpg'],
# ['user/folder1/1.txt', 'user/folder1/blah.txt'],
# ['user/folder1/folder2/random.txt'],
# ['user/folder3/folder4/folder5/1.txt',
#  'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/3.txt',
#  'user/folder3/folder4/folder5/2.txt']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import collections
results = defaultdict(list)
for path in files:
    results[os.path.dirname(path)].append(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you, getting the set of unique directories and then using nested list comprehension.

```
from os.path import dirname

unique_dirs = set(dirname(s) for s in files)
output = [[f for f in files if dirname(f) == directory] 
          for directory in unique_dirs]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this

```
>>> sorted_files = [ x for x in sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.count("/"))]
>>> max_dash = max([x.count("/") for x in sorted_files])
>>> max_dash
4
>>> newlist = [[y for y in sorted_files if y.count("/")==x] for x in range(max_dash)]
>>> newlist
[[], ['user/hey.jpg', 'user/1.jpg'], ['user/folder1/1.txt', 'user/folder1/blah.txt'], ['user/folder1/folder2/random.txt']]
```